# How to track or log time for system utilization?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, cpu-usage

Using c#, I want to create a console program which can calculate system utilization time. That is the time between when it starts and stops. The time when system goes to sleep should be excluded.

For example, if a person starts system at 1:00 PM and shuts it down at 2:00 PM with a sleep time of 10 minutes. I want to calculate start time, shutdown time and sleep time. This way, I can get the system utilization for a given session.

Thank you.

Comment: When you say "sleep" time, are you referring to the power state, e.g. when you close the lid of your laptop? (See [System Sleeping States](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff564575(v=vs.85).aspx) ).

Comment: Yes you are right. I just don't want to include sleep time during system active session.